# Update Item without touching Values

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to SQL to query an Object from DB.
I pass it via wcf to a Client Application, the Client App does some Changes on the Values and sends the Object back.
What I now want to do is updating the DB's Item to take the new Values.
UNfortunately it is very hard to first select the object by a query statement, modify about 100 values and then submit changes back.

Is there any smarter way to update the Record using linq-to-sql without touching the Values?
My thought was, if i still have the ready object that linq is able to insert, if there is a way to just overwrite the existing one in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use the [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978) method. In your case probably [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548778) is appropriate.

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/10/08/attach-if-you-have-something-detached.aspx) gives some neat information.